# 配列内の順番変更を行うには？

Tags: c#

string[] stArray = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" , "D" };

→ACBD
このように
例えばCをAの後に移動させ
その後の配列値は順番通りBDと続くような
配列操作を行うにはどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: BLUEPIXYさんの回答をみて気になったのですが、質問文は遠回りの説明をしているだけで２要素の交換を行いたいのでしょうか？ それとも質問文通り要素の移動（任意要素の削除と挿入）を行いたいのでしょうか？ 文字通り読めば後者だと思うのですが…。

Comment: 上手く説明できず申し訳ございません。後者です

Answer (score 2, accepted):

配列は固定長ですので、可変長の[`List<T>`クラス](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)を使用すると操作しやすいです。

```
var strings = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", };
strings.Remove("C");
strings.Insert(strings.IndexOf("A") + 1, "C");
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(strings));
// → ACBD
```

また`ToArray()`メソッドを使用すれば配列に変換できます。

---

pgrhoさんが指摘されるように私の回答では`Remove()`メソッドで前に詰める際のコピーと`Insert()`メソッドで後ろにずらす際のコピーとが発生するため、`MoveElement<T>()`のようなメソッドを利用した方が効率はいいです。
ただし、呼び出し回数が少ないのであればその差による影響も小さく、`MoveElement<T>()`のように行いたい操作に応じたメソッドをそれぞれ用意するか既存の`Remove()` `Insert()`などで簡単に済ますかは考慮の余地があります。
逆に呼び出し回数が多ければ影響も大きくなりますが、今度は配列全体に渡る操作になっているはずであり、`MoveElement<T>()`のようなメソッドを利用するのではなくアルゴリズム自体を見直すべきです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
ちなみにインデックス番号によって操作することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: @MAHOTO さん、詳細はリンク先を参照ください。`Insert`はインデックスによる操作しかできません。`Remove`の代わりに`RemoveAt`が用意されています。

Answer (score 2):

新しい配列を作成せずに特定のインデックスの要素を別のインデックスに移動し、間にある要素を前または後ろにずらす場合、以下のような操作になります。

```
static void MoveElement<T>(T[] array, int currentIndex, int newIndex)
{
    // 現在の要素の値を退避する
    var temp = array[currentIndex];

    // 移動方向を判定する
    if (currentIndex < newIndex)
    {
        // currentIndex＜i≦newIndexの要素を1個ずつ前方へ移動する
        Array.Copy(array, currentIndex + 1, array, currentIndex, newIndex - currentIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        // newIndex≦i＜currentIndexの要素を1個ずつ後方へ移動する
        Array.Copy(array, newIndex, array, newIndex + 1, currentIndex - newIndex);
    }

    // 退避した値をnewIndexに設定
    array[newIndex] = temp;
}
```

間の要素の移動には`Array.Copy`を使用していますが、一般のリストであれば`for`ステートメントを使用することになります。

`List<T>`での削除や挿入は対象インデックス以降のすべての要素を移動することになりますので、削除と挿入を組み合わせて移動を行うと後方の本来移動しなくてよい要素も前後に2回コピーされることになります。ですリストの要素数が多い場合は明示的に操作した方が効率が良くなります。

Answer (score 0):

配列の１番目の要素`"B"`と２番目の`"C"`を入れ替えるには次のようにします。

```
string temp = stArray[2];
stArray[2] = stArray[1];
stArray[1] = temp;
```

[デモ](http://ideone.com/QQ5lqO)

Comment: 配列のある範囲のローテーションをする場合は結局この操作の延長繰り返しになります。(pgrhoさんの回答が参考になります）、配‌​列を使用する場合このような挿入・削除につ‌​いては並びの要素を移動する必要があるので‌​、このような操作が頻発するようなら配列以‌​外の構造を使用した方がいいかもしれません‌​。