# 前行番号と後行番号を指示して並び替える方法

Tags: c#, .net

以下のように前行番号と後行番号を指示して並び替えたいです。どのようにすれば良いでしょうか。
対象のフレームワークは.NET Framework 4.7.2で、IDEはVisual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.3.10です。
OSは、Windows 10 1903です。

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> oldDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    oldDictionary.Add(1, "日本円");
    oldDictionary.Add(2, "アメリカドル");
    oldDictionary.Add(3, "オーストラリアドル");
    oldDictionary.Add(4, "ニュージーランドドル");

    foreach (var item in oldDictionary.OrderBy((x) => x.Key))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "_" + item.Value);
    }

    Dictionary<int, string> newDictionary = ChangeOrder(oldDictionary, 2, 4);
    foreach (var item in newDictionary.OrderBy((x) => x.Key))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "" + item.Value);
    }
    //欲しい結果（2番目のアメリカドルを4番目にする。あとは元の並び順通り）
    //1 日本円
    //2 オーストラリアドル
    //3 ニュージーランドドル
    //4 アメリカドル

    newDictionary = ChangeOrder(oldDictionary, 1, 3);
    foreach (var item in newDictionary.OrderBy((x) => x.Key))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "" + item.Value);
    }
    //欲しい結果（1番目の日本円を3番目にする。あとは元の並び順通り）
    //1 アメリカドル
    //2 オーストラリアドル
    //3 日本円
    //4 ニュージーランドドル

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static Dictionary<int, string> ChangeOrder(Dictionary<int, string> oldDictionary, int 前行No, int 後行No)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> newDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    //何らかの処理
    return newDictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

入れ替えの考え方は以下の記事と類似の考え方で、いったんListにしてから入れ替え、新たにDictionaryを作るやり方で行きます。
[配列内の順番変更を行うには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/35963/26370)

以下のようになります。行番号の引数名は srcno, dstno に変えました。

```
static Dictionary<int, string> ChangeOrder(Dictionary<int, string> oldDictionary, int srcno, int dstno)
{
    // 行番号の範囲チェックが必要ならばこの場所で行う。

    // 元のDictionaryの値をkey(行番号)でソートしてリスト化
    List<string> valuelist = new List<string>();
    foreach (var d in oldDictionary.OrderBy((e) => e.Key))
    {
        valuelist.Add(d.Value);
    }

    // 行番号1オリジンをリストインデックス0オリジンに変換
    srcno--;
    dstno--;

    // リストによる位置の入れ替え
    string temp = valuelist[srcno];
    valuelist.RemoveAt(srcno);
    valuelist.Insert(dstno, temp);

    // 新しいDictionaryの作成
    Dictionary<int, string> newDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    int key = 1;  // keyは1オリジン
    foreach (string s in valuelist)
    {
        newDictionary.Add(key++, s);
    }
    return newDictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linqを使って新しいディクショナリを作成する方法です。
`前行No > 後行No`の場合も想定しています。

使用する場合は下記の留意点にご注意ください

- ディクショナリのキーを入れ替える処理に複数の三項演算子を使って可読性が低い
- 連続したキー番号のみを想定している
- 最初にキー番号で並べ替えている

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> oldDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            oldDictionary.Add(1, "日本円");
            oldDictionary.Add(2, "アメリカドル");
            oldDictionary.Add(3, "オーストラリアドル");
            oldDictionary.Add(4, "ニュージーランドドル");

            foreach (var item in oldDictionary.OrderBy((x) => x.Key))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "_" + item.Value);
            }

            Dictionary<int, string> newDictionary = ChangeOrder(oldDictionary, 2, 4);
            foreach (var item in newDictionary.OrderBy((x) => x.Key))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "" + item.Value);
            }
            //欲しい結果（2番目のアメリカドルを4番目にする。あとは元の並び順通り）
            //1 日本円
            //2 オーストラリアドル
            //3 ニュージーランドドル
            //4 アメリカドル

            newDictionary = ChangeOrder(oldDictionary, 1, 3);
            foreach (var item in newDictionary.OrderBy((x) => x.Key))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "" + item.Value);
            }
            //欲しい結果（1番目の日本円を3番目にする。あとは元の並び順通り）
            //1 アメリカドル
            //2 オーストラリアドル
            //3 日本円
            //4 ニュージーランドドル

            ChangeOrder(oldDictionary, 4, 1).OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList().ForEach(item =>
             {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "" + item.Value);
            });
            //結果（4番目のニュージーランドドルを1番目にする。あとは元の並び順通り）
            //1 ニュージーランドドル
            //2 日本円
            //3 アメリカドル
            //4 オーストラリアドル

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static Dictionary<int, string> ChangeOrder(Dictionary<int, string> oldDictionary, int src, int dst)
        {
            // 行番号の範囲チェックが必要ならばこの場所で行う。

            // Dictionaryをコピーして並べ替え
            var dic = new SortedDictionary<int, string>(oldDictionary);
            // 入れ替える並び順を変える係数
            var addition = (src < dst) ? -1 : 1;
            return dic
                    .Select(p => new { k = (p.Key < Math.Min(src, dst) || p.Key > Math.Max(src, dst)) ? p.Key : (p.Key == src) ? dst : p.Key + addition, v = p.Value })
                    .ToDictionary(p => p.k, p => p.v);
        }
    }
}
```